# What would it happen when creating mutiple input & output steam reader / writer base on one socket?

Tags: java, sockets

Assume I have a program:

```java
Class A {
    Socket a;
    public void methodOne() {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        // Do something
    }
    public void methodtwo() {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        // Do something
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        methodOne();
        methodTwo();
    }
}
```

What would it happen? Could it cause any unsupposed consequence?

Comment: It's definitely not going to do anything predictable. What do you want to achieve by creating this?

Comment: Input will get lost and outpit will get interleaved. Don't do this. Associate a single reader and writer with the socket for the life of the socket.

Comment: I'm helping my classmate modify his code and at first I thought it was only a bad habit but could lead to correct result ....